# Can the Arduino interface with a fingerprint sensor on my mobile?

Tags: sensors

I own a OnePlus 6 and it has a fingerprint sensor. Instead of using a fingerprint scanner module like the R305, could I just use my mobile for scanning the fingerprints? If yes, how do I implement this?

This is for creating a smart home security system.

Comment: JRobert has a good point in his answer. what for to send the fingerprint to arduino if the phone is already authenticated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need an app on your mobile to read the sensor and communicate the result to your Arduino *in a secure way* that cannot be spoofed by an intruder. That secure communication over an open channel (WiFi, I assume?) is not trivial to do right, so that would be a weak point in your security.

[Blynk](https://www.blynk.cc/), an app+server+Arduino library combination provides an authentication token to pair with your Arduino in a relatively secure way. You quickly make (drag-and-drop) a control panel for your Arduino system with it. It doesn't offer fingerprint sensing directly, but if you keep your Blynk authentication token a secret, keep your Blynk app+token on your mobile, and the mobile is fingerprint-locked, you'd have essentially the same thing, and the pieces already exist. You'd only need to code the smart-home parts for the Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes it is possible.

1. Write an app for your phone that scans your fingerprint and does "something" with it.
2. Decide on (and implement) some form of communication protocol between the phone and the Arduino and send data from the phone depending on what you decide the "something" above is.
3. Write a sketch for your Arduino that responds to that communication protocol and performs whatever task you require.

The Arduino side of things, effectively, has nothing at all to do with the fingerprint scanner - it just accepts data from your phone. The fact that the phone is generating that data using the fingerprint scanner as a stimulus is of no importance to the Arduino.

99% of the work for the fingerprint scanner will be done on the phone, and done using phone software. Not Arduino software.

Answer (score 1):

Majenko in his answer described how to do it if you can code an application for phone. Other option is a little  overkill, but should be a ready solution. You could use 1Shield. It is a shield, a library and a phone app to use phone resources with Arduino. It supports fingerprint sensor. I have no experience with it, I only read about it.